# Non-transparent child of semi-transparent parent element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a top-navigation which get's semi-transparent when it's not hovered.

```
nav.top-bar {
  background: none;
  opacity: 0.6;
  transition: opacity 0.4s;
}

nav.top-bar:hover{
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

This navigation contains a search-field. It searches live via AJAX and displays the search-results below the search-field.

However it's a child of the top navigation as well which gets semi-transparent when not hovered. Therefore the search-results get semi-transparent too.

[image]
[image]

**How can I prevent it from becoming semi-transparent?**

**EDIT:** Applying transparency to background and text-color of the top-navigation won't work because it also contains images.

**EDIT2:** You can check out the problem on my homepage.
Therefore go to http://midifight.club/blog , put something like "ali" in the search. The results will apear. Now drag your mouse somewhere else and drag it again to the search-results. Nothing will happen.

Comment: You can't, that's how it works, when you set an elements opacity it affects all elements inside that element as well. A workaround would be to set the backround to RGBA, but that would require an actual background

Comment: 1. remove opacity. 2. add `background: rgba()` like rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)  3. add `color : rgba()` just like with the background. Color can get inherited so just change that on your searchfield. While background is only on the element itself

Comment: instead of making the entire element transparent, just do the css properties you need: `background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.5); border: 1px solid rgba(0,255,0,0.5);`

Comment: That won't work since the top-navigation also contains <img> which would look silly if they were not transparent.

Comment: @Hedge then set the image to semi transparent as well

Comment: can you set a fiddle or codepen online, to see what is the deal with your background-image/image ? cause opacity can be applied to image, rgba() used, box-shadow-inset as well along with background-position eventually. each case has its way :)

Comment: Better see the problem on the homepage itself. I added instructions to see the problem in action in the original question.

I couldn't reproduce the problem in a JSFiddle. There when I dragged above the search-results the nav-bar was counted as hovered which works very good.

Comment: Honestly it looks fine, I don't even think it needs fixing. You can always move the search out of the header in the DOM and position it back where it needs to be with css

Comment: In Chrome and Safari the Z-order is totally wrong as soon as it gets semi-transparent. I attached a screenshot to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution that comes to mind is to add a class to the navigation that will prevent it from going transparent when something is searched for.

## css

```
.top-bar.focused { opacity: 1 !important; }
```

## JS

```
document.getElementById('searchBox').oninput = function(){
    if(this.value){
        document.getElementById('top-bar').classList.add('focused');
    }else{
        document.getElementById('top-bar').classList.remove('focused');
    }
}
```

Obviously this will not work straight away, I'm just giving you an idea.

**EDIT**

Firefox' 3d view can be really helpful in times like this

[image]

As you can see the search results appear on top of the other content, which means that the bugs are entirely caused by opacity and not z-indexes. You can also get to this conclusion by hovering over the menu and seeing that it appears on top when not faded, if it were a z-index problem then it wouldn't appear on top even when it was non-transparent.

Comment: that's very clever. Since I manage everything related to appearing and disappearing of the search-results myself I can make this work.

I won't mark this answered yet because I'm eager to know why the Z-order is so f'ed up.

Comment: @Hedge I added some info on the "z-order"

Comment: Is the opacity behaviour really buggy or did I use it wrong? Now if I could just have a tuna sandwich I'd be 100% sure that this is the answer I was looking for :D just joking, thanks a ton!

Comment: @Hedge can't really tell you, I'm not very good with CSS, but I suppose what I suggested would work, or at least I hope so :D

Comment: I implemented it and it fixed the problem as you expected. thanks a lot.